# Rails regex for validation of Google Maps latitude longitude

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, validation

I'm trying to do a `validates_format_of` on the latlng object that is passed back from Google Maps API. I've got the map set up perfectly so that when I click on a point in the map it fills in a text-field with the latlng (which looks like this: 46.320615137905904, 9.400520324707031). I'm storing this value as a string in the db (which I then parse out to place markers on the map later) but I need to validate the format of the sting as two floats (positive or negative) with a comma in between.

I know that this is possible with regex but for the life of my haven't been able to figure out the regex string to get it working.

Any help would be super appreciated! Thanks!
Jeff

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`/^-?\d+\.\d+\,\s?-?\d+\.\d+$/`

- `^` matches the beginning of the
- `$` matches the end of the string
- `-?` matches an optional minus sign
- `\d+` matches 1 or more digits
- `\.` mathces a dot (you have to escape it because `.` matches any character)
- `\s?` matches an optional whitespace

You may want to accept whitespaces at the beginning or at the end:

`/^\s*-?\d+\.\d+\,\s?-?\d+\.\d+\s*$/`

Comment: Tested and works http://rubular.com/r/efAZkpiNMl.
One suggestion @Leventix: `/^\s*[-+]?\d+\.\d+\,\s?[-+]?\d+\.\d+\s*$/` allowing both + and -. Cool solution btw. :)

Comment: Another suggestion: `/^\s*[-+]?\d{1,3}\.\d+\,\s?[-+]?\d{1,3}\.\d+\s*$/` - since Lat and Long should be between 0 and 180.

Comment: Cheers guys! And thanks for the explanation - that will help me having to ask later on!

Comment: Unrelated and old, but escaping the comma is unnecessary.

Answer (score 10):

I'm validating this way:

```
var ck_lat = /^-?([1-8]?\d(?:\.\d{1,})?|90(?:\.0{1,6})?)$/;
var ck_lon = /^-?((?:1[0-7]|[1-9])?\d(?:\.\d{1,})?|180(?:\.0{1,})?)$/;
var lat = 89.320615;
var lon = 179.400520;

if(ck_lat.test(lat) && ck_lon.test(lon)) {
    //Was a valid latitude and longitude pair :)
}
```

This is on development stage, but it works ok, here is the link for testing both regexp:

Check Latitude: http://rubular.com/r/vodC5TW3lG

Check Longitude: http://rubular.com/r/3LIIcjFEQT

EDIT:
Thanks to  Tim Kelly for the improvement, this one catches -90 / -180, i think now is complete :)
Links and code edited.

Comment: FWIW, your solution catches most, but doesn't catch -90 or -180, respectively...but is REALLY close!  :)  Just move the "-?" outside the first parenthesis like so: "/^-?([1-8]?\d(?:\.\d{1,})?|90(?:\.0{1,6})?)$/" for the latitude, and:  "/^-?((?:1[0-7]|[1-9])?\d(?:\.\d{1,})?|180(?:\.0{1,})?)$/" for longitude.  Cheers!

Answer (score 6):

It is possible with a Regex, however you may find it easier to use split as follows

```
latitude, longitude = latlong.split(',')
```

And then check the numericality of the two variables.

Comment: I prefer this solution, because it also lends itself to range-checking the values (should be between -180 to 180).

Comment: @Chris -180 to +180 is good for longitude, latitude is -90 to +90

Answer (score 1):

Latitude ranges from -90 to 90
Longitude ranges from -180 to 180

I have used a regex which evaluate values which falls between the range having 4-6 decimal points (since in google maps api mostly 6 decimal points precision is used)

**Latitude**: `/^(-?(90\.0{4,6})|([0-8]\d{0,1})\.\d{4,6})$/`

http://rubular.com/r/UpY74Y4fuG

**Longitude:** `/^(-?((180)\.0{4,6})|((1[0-7][0-9])|([0-9]\d{0,1}))\.\d{4,6})$/`

http://rubular.com/r/OQ0KS7puhv